# load data in table view after scrolling to bottom

Tags: uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a initial table unreadmessagesArrays, witch is displayed perfectly.
but a want to scroll to bottom and load an another rows of data ..
i used this :

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{

CGFloat currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
CGFloat maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height;

if (maximumOffset - currentOffset <= 10.0) {
      [self insertRowInTableView];
        }
}


-(void)insertRowInTableView {
[self.unreadmessagesArray addObject:self.messagesIfScroll];

[mytableView beginUpdates];
NSArray *paths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([self.unreadmessagesArray count] - 1) inSection:0]];
[mytableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:NO];
[mytableView endUpdates];
[mytableView reloadData];

}

-(void)getMessagesIfScollToBottom {
self.messagesIfScroll = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:responseA];

}
```

the error i get is : `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa20b620'`

Where is the problem ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your code use this code

`[self.unreadmessagesArray addObjectsFromArray:self.messagesIfScroll];`

instead of `[self.unreadmessagesArray addObject:self.messagesIfScroll];`

Comment: what is the type of 'unreadmessagesArray'? is this is NSMutableArray or  NSArray?

Comment: both unreadmessageaArray, and messagesIfScroll are NSMutalearray !